# Detailed treatment of a liquid-gas phase transition in Landau Theory approach

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, mean-field-theory

I have been studying the Landau theory for critical second order phase transitions.

I am looking for a specific and detailed treatment of a liquid-gas phase transition near the critical point. Many treatments I have seen default to the example of magnetization. For example in Chapter 8 and then 13 of Peskin & Schroeder's "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" magnetization is treated.

In the second paragraph on pg. 272 and in table 13.1, the treatment of a liquid-gas transition as part of the N=1 d=3 universality class is mentioned but no concrete reference given. There is a reference to Zinn-Justin 1993 but it is from an old edition of the book (now on the 5th edition) and I'm not sure how the chapter corresponds in the newer edition (and I don't have the full reference to peruse).

Does someone know of a reference that gives the treatment I am looking for? It would also be nice to have a treatment that uses L theory beyond the critical point in the first-order region. I am aware that L theory can do that, confirmed by [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/407773/) but also have not seen a treatment of this.

Comment: I think Goldenfeld's book "*Lectures on Phase Transitions and the Renormalization Group*" contains what you are looking for. Although confined to a neighbor of the critical point, the discussion is general enough to allow to get conclusions on the first-order liquid-gas transition.